# Load ASP.Net MVC JSONResult jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I'm trying to get the DataTables(http://datatables.net) to work with a JsonResult returned by an ASP.Net MVC Controller. I keep getting a "DataTables warning (table id = 'example'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0" error which according to the docs means it cant find the columns.

The code in controller that returns the JsonResult looks like:

```
    public JsonResult LoadPhoneNumbers()
    {
        List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        PhoneNumber num1 = new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 123 4567", Description = "George" };
        PhoneNumber num2 = new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 765 4321", Description = "Kevin" };
        PhoneNumber num3 = new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 555 4781", Description = "Sam" };

        phoneNumbers.Add(num1);
        phoneNumbers.Add(num2);
        phoneNumbers.Add(num3);

        return Json(phoneNumbers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

PhoneNumber is just a plain C# class with 2 properties, Number and Description.

The javascript that retrieves and loads the data looks like:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '/Account/LoadPhoneNumbers/',
        "sAjaxDataProp": ""
    });
});
</script>
```

And the html looks like:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Number
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

I've deliberately set sAjaxDataProp to an empty string so that DataTables does not look for aaData. Even when I explicitly set aaData like so in the controller:

```
return Json(new { aaData = phoneNumbers });
```

I still get the error. Any advice please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following works great for me:

```
$(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        bProcessing: true,
        sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("LoadPhoneNumbers", "Home")'
    });
});
```

I have removed the `sAjaxDataProp` property.

with this data source:

```
public ActionResult LoadPhoneNumbers()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        aaData = new[] 
        {
            new [] { "Trident", "Internet Explorer 4.0", "Win 95+", "4", "X" },
            new [] { "Gecko", "Firefox 1.5", "Win 98+ / OSX.2+", "1.8", "A" },
            new [] { "Webkit", "iPod Touch / iPhone", "iPod", "420.1", "A" }
        }
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and for your example with phones simply:

```
public ActionResult LoadPhoneNumbers()
{
    var phoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>(new[] 
    {
        new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 123 4567", Description = "George" },
        new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 765 4321", Description = "Kevin" },
        new PhoneNumber { Number = "555 555 4781", Description = "Sam" }
    });

    return Json(new
    {
        aaData = phoneNumbers.Select(x => new[] { x.Number, x.Description })
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the problem is with the way the PhoneNumbers class gets serialized.. if you look in fiddler the JSON looks like this:
[{"Number":"555 123 4567","Description":"George"},{"Number":"555 765 4321","Description":"Kevin"},{"Number":"555 555 4781","Description":"Sam"}]

How would one go about removing the property names Number and Description?

Comment: @PW763, yes, the problem is with the way you are formatting your JSON. Please see my updated answer with an example of how to format the phone numbers correctly.

Comment: Hi, Dari, i have faced similar issue. I'm sure u will be knowing the ans, i have framed new question, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352736/controller-method-is-not-hitting-in-datatables-c-sharp-mvc

Comment: script fails whit 'aDataSort' missing argument.

Comment: you need to add "columns":[ your col values] param to your DataTable script code.

Answer (score 0):

In this [example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JQuery-DataTables-MVC.aspx) it appears that the data returned from the controller method needs to be in a specific format. He's actually returning the list as part of aaData. It also explains what each parameter is for. Perhaps you're just not formatting the return in a json format that DataTables understands.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AjaxHandler(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        return Json(new{
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                iTotalRecords = 97,
                iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
                aaData = new List<string[]>() {
                    new string[] {"1", "a1", "a2", "a3"},
                    new string[] {"2", "b1", "b2", "b3"},
                    new string[] {"3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}
                    }
            },
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, is your HTML tag closed or was it just a copy/paste error.