# JQuery Datatable plugin data binding in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, datatables

I am trying to use JQuery Datatable plugin in ASP.NET MVC application. However, although my controller returns JSON data to plugin, the table shows a `Loading...` message and stuck there.

This is my controller,

```
public ActionResult GetCompanies(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
   return Json(new
   {
       sEcho = param.sEcho,
       iTotalRecords = 97,
       iTotalDisplayRecords = 3,
       aaData = new List<string[]>() {
           new string[] {"1", "a1", "a2", "a3"},
           new string[] {"2", "b1", "b2", "b3"},
           new string[] {"3", "c1", "c2", "c3"}
           }
       }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
}
```

This is the initialization of datatable plugin.

```
$('#companyDataTable').dataTable({
    bProcessing: true,
    sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("GetCompanies", "Company")'
});
```

This is the screenshot of my table.

[image]

This is the JSON data returned to plugin from `Company/GetCompanies`

```
{ "sEcho":null,
  "iTotalRecords":97,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords":3,
  "aaData":[ ["1","a1","a2","a3"],
             ["2","b1","b2","b3"],
             ["3","c1","c2","c3"]
           ]
}
```

`jQuerDataTableParamModel` is a class which is shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part). I also tried answers on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835960/load-asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-jquery-datatables) but none of them are working for me.

**EDIT :**

This is how plugin request looks like.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Your `param` model is not initialized for some reason. Try to check request parameters in browser, using developer tools. Also, try to change the argument name - maybe you have another request parameter called `param`.

Comment: changed my source to sAjaxSource: 'GetCompanies'. Now it is working. Do you know what might cause this ? btw thanks for directing me.

Comment: Not a problem. Just `'GetCompanies'`? No `@Url.Action` call? That should work if you are currently on `/Company` page... then `/Company/GetCompanies` should be requested. Not sure why it's not working with `@Url.Action`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the same sEcho value that your request had. In your response, "sEcho" value is null, so DataTables cannot connect request with response.

From DataTables [documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side):

> **sEcho** An unaltered copy of sEcho sent from the client side. This parameter will change with each draw (it is basically a draw count) -
>   so it is important that this is implemented. Note that it strongly
>   recommended for security reasons that you 'cast' this parameter to an
>   integer in order to prevent Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am using param.sEcho to return the sEcho value but the controller receives it as null, this is why it is null in response. Do you have any idea why it is null ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi That's strange... How does your request look like? Does it send sEcho parameter?

Comment: as far as I know, you don't explicitly make requests. plugin initialization code has the URL 'Company/GetCompanies', and it makes first request to that action method when it is being initialized. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi yes, but you can see both request and response using browser developer tools, like Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: And also, you could set a breakpoint in your action method and check the values there.

Comment: sorry I misunderstand you :) I updated my question with the screenshot of request.

Answer (score 0):

Probably way too late for the OP, but I'm guessing you were using version 1.10 of DataTables?

The incoming parameters are quite different from earlier version which is why the custom object in that tutorial (jQueryDataTableParamMode)  is not having any values bound to it's properties.

At this time, the up-to-date documentation for version 1.10 for the incoming variables is [enter link description here](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

You can see this talks about a variable called "draw" which replaces the old "sEcho"

The same documentation page for version 1.9 or earlier is [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side)

Furthermore [here is a comparison list](http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) for upgrading from 1.9 to 1.10