# .NET MVC Datatables response works, table doesn't render

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a Services controller with an action:

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public JsonResult GetDrugClasses()
    {
        var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
        var drugClasses = new List<DrugClassTable>();
        drugClasses = dataAccess.GetDrugClasses();
        return Json(drugClasses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And in my view I have:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DrugColorID</th>
            <th>DrugColorDescription</th>
            <th>DrugClass</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': '/Services/GetDrugClasses',
        'aoColumns': [
            { 'sName': 'DrugColorId' },
            { 'sName': 'DrugColorDescription' },
            { 'sName': 'DrugClass' }
            ]
    });
</script>
```

When I open up dev tools I can see the the request was successful and the correct response was received.  When I use the above code I get a JavaScript error: `Cannot read property length of undefined` on line 2038 of the data tables version hosted here: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.js

I have a Model with three lists which I will need to use client-side paging on.  Datatables renders the search box, columns and paging controls correctly, just not the data.  What am I missing here?

sample JSON:

```
 [
   {
      "DrugClass":"A1A",
      "DrugDescription":"DIGITALIS GLYCOSIDES                                        "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A1B",
      "DrugDescription":"XANTHINES                                                   "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A1C",
      "DrugDescription":"INOTROPIC DRUGS                                             "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A1D",
      "DrugDescription":"GENERAL BRONCHODILATOR AGENTS                               "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A1E",
      "DrugDescription":"XANTHINES/DIETARY SUPPLEMENT COMBINATIONS                   "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A2A",
      "DrugDescription":"ANTIARRHYTHMICS                                             "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A2B",
      "DrugDescription":"ANTIANGINAL, HEART RATE REDUCING, I(F) INHIBITOR            "
   },
   {
      "DrugClass":"A2C",
      "DrugDescription":"ANTIANGINAL & ANTI-ISCHEMIC AGENTS,NON-HEMODYNAMIC          "
   }
]
```

model:

```
 public IEnumerable<DrugClassTable> DrugClasses { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SideEffects> SideEffects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DrugColor> DrugColors { get; set; }
```

DrugColor:

```
public class DrugColor
    {
        public int DrugColorId { get; set; }
        public string DrugColorDescription { get; set; }
        public string DrugClass { get; set; }
    }
```

DrugClassTable

```
public class DrugClassTable
    {
        public string DrugClass { get; set; }
        public string DrugDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us your model?

Comment: Paste the JSON returned by your controller - first couple of rows.

Comment: Where's the ID? There's supposed to be a DrugColorId.

Comment: @MiniRagnarok the id to the table is in the HTML, myTable

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Sorry. I was asking about the DrugColorId.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Also, that's not your model. DrugClassTable is your model.

Comment: I think your return may have to be wrapped `[ "aaData" : (above json data here) ]`

Comment: Also make sure your table has valid markup.. i.e. it needs a `<tbody>` element

Comment: @zgood added that element and changed the model, I'm still getting the same error as before

Comment: @wootscootinboogie I've never used this plugin before but it's possible that you have to supply it the other three parameters. sEcho, iTotalRecords, and iTotalDisplayRecords.

Answer (score 0):

How large is the dataset you are pulling down in GetDrugClasses? It's possible your method returns an incomplete/malformatted value (null, perhaps?) where datatables isn't expecting it.

Step one is modify your controller and say, do Take(10) or Take(1) on GetDrugClasses (in case a value is malformatted, let's see if even the first few items work or not). If that still fails, try mocking out a fake DrugClass object with manually set string values. If that doesn't work, try maybe an older/newer version of the dataTables library (in case its a datatables bug).

Comment: It's relatively small (140 records), but taking 10 didn't get my a different result.

Answer (score 0):

You set up your table to expect `DrugColor` but you sent `DrugClassTable`.

I assume that you meant to set your table up for `DrugClassTable`. Change that and see if it works.

For example,

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DrugClass </th>
            <th>DrugDescription </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myTable').dataTable({
        'bServerSide': true,
        'sAjaxSource': '/Services/GetDrugClasses',
        'aoColumns': [
            { 'sName': 'DrugClass' },
            { 'sName': 'DrugDescription ' }
            ]
    });
</script>
```

As other people have mentioned, the json return is wrong. It should look like this:

```
{
  "aaData": [
    [
       {
          "DrugClass":"A1A",
          "DrugDescription":"DIGITALIS GLYCOSIDES                               "
       },
       {
          "DrugClass":"A1B",
          "DrugDescription":"XANTHINES                                                   "
       }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here's an [example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html) of how to set this up.

Comment: If I'm consuming a service that I wrote, how would one add a property like 'aaData' to the returned JSON?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie You could look at how Darin did it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835960/load-asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-jquery-datatables