# unable to fetch data from DB using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC application. I want to get data from database using ajax. It does not load data in web page and also there is no error on the console window and is no exception in visual studio. 
Following is my Controller code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetCompanies()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Company> company = _companyService.GetCompanies().ToList();
            IEnumerable<CompanyListViewModel> viewModelListCompanies = Mapper.DynamicMap<IEnumerable<Company>, IEnumerable<CompanyListViewModel>>(company);


            return new JsonSuccessResult(viewModelListCompanies);
            //return Json(accountTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)ResponseCode.UnprocessableEntity;
            return new JsonErrorResult(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is the code in my view.

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9">

        <div class="block">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Sortable table</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-striped sortable" id="myDbTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th data-hide width="20%">ID</th>
                            <th data-hide width="20%">Name</th>
                            <th data-hide width="20%">E-mail</th>
                            <th data-hide width="20%">Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

   }
     @section Scripts{
    <script>

    var DataColumnsCount = 4;

    //***Start Fatching Data for datatable *** start //

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: @Url.Action("GetCompanies","Company"),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "{}",
        success: fetchCompanyTableList});
function fetchCompanyTableList() {

    $('#myDbTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: @Url.Action("GetCompanies", "Company"),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            dataSrc: 'DataSet',

        },
        "columns": [
                {"data" : "Id"},
                { "data": "Name" },
               { "data": "Email" },
                { "data": "Owner" }


        ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            {
                "aTargets": [DataColumnsCount],
                "mData": null,
                "bSortable": false,
                "mRender": function (data, type, fullRow) {
                    return '<th width="20%"><a href="#">Details</a></th>';
                }
            }
        ]

    }
      );


}
```

I am unable to figure out what really i am doing wrong. Please someone help in this regard.

Comment: What you get in response to Ajax request?.(check in inspect->Network->XHR on chrome).

Comment: Its giving: status code 200 ok

Comment: and GetCompanies method of the controller is  not found. This means that it is not getting my controller GET code.. What should I do here now?

Comment: There should be call back function into first ajax   - In you first Ajax 
success: function(result) {
if(result != null )
  // call the function
fetchCompanyTableList();
}

Comment: There is no need of first ajax call. Just use ajax call within datatable.

Answer (score 2):

For Datatable You need Change TYPE to [HttpPost] & in you ajax change type "POST"
As a developer you need add breakpoint to your controller & check its getting hit or not .
Also you can console.log() / see result in browser developer tool

Answer (score 1):

You use `[HttpGet]` in your action , means only allow http `GET` request in your action.
But your `ajax` call you use `POST` request . That's not accept in your action. so change `POST` to `GET` if you need `GET` request OR change `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]` for `POST` request .

You do't need  multiple `ajax` call.so need to change your ajax call because jquery datatable has own ajax call for data loading. you can fiend your answer [this](https://cmatskas.com/server-side-jquery-datatables-with-asp-net/) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835960/load-asp-net-mvc-jsonresult-jquery-datatables) link. Or you can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgD24a9gxXw) YouTube video.

Comment: By changing TYPE to GET it is gettitng data in dataset but not populating in the table. can you please tell me why is it not getting displayed in the table so that i may mark your answer