# Data not rendering in the table using datatables

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am implementing datatable. I can see data is coming from database in xhr using developer tools but it is not showing in the table. Please tell me what is the problem with my code.

```
@section Body{
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-9">

        <div class="block">

            <div class="content">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table" id="myDbTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th data-hide>ID</th>
                            <th data-hide >Name</th>
                            <th data-hide >E-mail</th>
                            <th data-hide>Phone</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

}
  @section Scripts{
<script>

    var DataColumnsCount = 4;

    //***Start Fatching Data for datatable *** start //





function fetchEmployeeTableList() {

    $('#myDbTable').DataTable({

        "columns": [
               {"data" : "Id"},
               { "data": "Name" },
               { "data": "Email" },
                { "data": "Phone" }


        ]

    }
      );


}
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "@Url.Action("GetEmployees","Employee")",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "{}",
    dataSrc: 'DataSet',
success: fetchEmployeeTableList});




 </script>
}
```

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: You have now placed the AJAX-call outside the dataTable init, it looked better in your previous identical post  -> **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082963/unable-to-fetch-data-from-db-using-ajax** but for some reason you have decided to shuffle the JS in a different order...

Comment: After lot of research Both the ways are not working so i decided to ask another question.

Comment: Apparently your research did not include the dataTables docs. See **https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html** or **https://datatables.net/manual/ajax**